# How do we call GitLab API from c# application?

Tags: c#, api, gitlab

How do we call GitLab API using access token to get all the commits in a project.

I am getting unauthorized error.

```
string Url = "http://xxxxxx/DevOps/WebApp1.git/repository/commits";
using(var client = new WebClient()) //WebClient  
{
    client.BaseAddress = Url;
    //client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type:application/json"); //Content-Type  
    client.Headers.Add("Accept:application/json");
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer xxxxx";
    var commits_List = client.DownloadString(Url);
}
```

Comment: What authorization are you using?

Comment: i am using the GitLab authorization token. I have generated one token for this application. I am not sure what is the correct process to call GitLab APIs

Comment: Personal access token is not the same OAuth, read the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#personal-access-tokens)

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#personal-access-tokens) clearly states:

> You can use a personal access token to authenticate with the API by passing it in either the `private_token` parameter or the `Private-Token` header.

You are doing neither of them.

Remove your authorization header and replace it with this:

```
client.Headers["Private-Token"] = "xxxxx";
```

Comment: This doesnt work. I have access token. I dont know how to form the URL to access commits API.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{your_project_id}/repository/commits?private_token={your_private_token}
```